# Argument out of range - Card Shuffle

Tags: c#, game-engine, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle a deck of cards by randomly taking cards from one deck, and putting them into the other, to avoid getting duplicates of the cards once they are added to the new list they are removed from the original list, this seems to be causing the argument out of range error, despite my efforts to de-increment the range of the random number. Suggestions please?

```
List<Card> shuffledDeck = new List<Card> ();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 51; ++i) 
    {
        int c = myDeck.Count + 1;
        int n = rNumber.Next (1, c);
        shuffledDeck.Add(myDeck[n]);
        myDeck.Remove(myDeck[n]);
    }
```

Comment: First: what magic number is 51? Second, why `myDeck.Count + 1` and `rNumber.Next(1, c)`? List Indices are zero based, it looks like you constantly produce "off by one" errors.

Comment: Also, have you tried this oneliner `List<Card> shuffledDeck = myDeck.Orderby(_ => rNumber.Next()).ToList();` ? SO is full of this type of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   List<Card> shuffledDeck = new List<Card> ();

   while (myDeck.Count > 0)
   {
      int c = myDeck.Count;

      int n = rNumber.Next (0, c);
      var value = myDeck[n];
      shuffledDeck.Add(value);
      myDeck.Remove(value);

   }
```

You need to make sure you don't have an index more than actual array objects count.

Comment: When I make the change I am getting this message:

Error CS1955: The member `System.Collections.Generic.List<BlackJackGameX.Card>.Count' cannot be used as method or delegate (CS1955) (BlackJackGameX)

Comment: It says it is inaccessable due to its protection level?

Comment: Count is a property, so remove the ()

Comment: After I removed the () the initial problem remains, my console writes  writes a bunch of stuff, and says Parameter Index is out of range.

Comment: I am using Lists, not arrays if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JonDunn yes, my bad strike two, check again.

Comment: Thank you it works great now! At the risk of not learning anything from this, could you quickly explain why you used "var" in this instance?

Comment: var will translate into your type of element in the list/array at compile time. an accept and a vote up would be nice for the answer if it helped.

Comment: use this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx for learning about var

Comment: Thanks a lot man, answer accepted, I'm at 14 reputation at the minute, but once I'm over 15 i'll remember to come back and boost ya, I appreciate the link too thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26333/discussion-between-floradu88-and-jon-dunn)